# Should 'Common Connection Profile.yaml' include details about other organizations in a Hyperledger Fabric network?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I would like to seek clarification regarding the purpose and scope of the "Common Connection Profile.yaml" file in fabric network. Specifically, when creating this file for a particular organization, should all the details be exclusively focused on that organization, or should it encompass information pertaining to multiple organizations?

Taking the scenario of "common-connection-manufacture.yaml" as an example, I would like to understand if it is necessary to include details about other organizations within this file.

I think it should be details related to that orgonly

Answer (score 1):

The connection profile is just for the client application, and needs to contain enough information about the network for it to connect and transact successfully. How much information you need to put in there depends on your situation.

With Fabric v2.4 and above (including Fabric v2.5 LTS) using the [Fabric Gateway Client API](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/), you don't need a connection profile at all. Instead you just supply a gRPC connection to a Gateway peer within the network. More details in the documentation:

- [Migration guide: connection profiles](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway/migration#connection-profiles)
- [Running a Fabric Application tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/write_first_app.html#first-establish-a-grpc-connection-to-the-gateway)
- [Full Stack Asset Transfer workshop](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide/docs/ApplicationDev/01-FabricGateway.md)

With Fabric versions earlier than v2.4 (including Fabric v2.2 LTS), the requirements depend on whether or not your network is configured to use [service discovery](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/discovery-overview.html).

If using service discovery, the connection profile only needs to contain enough information for the client to connect to a single peer, from which it can obtain information about all the other network nodes using service discovery. There is a minimal example of this kind of connection profile [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/9bf4de090e02cf0f3a5595ae3b98c6dd45b92808/test/fixtures/profiles/network-discovery.json). You might want to include more than one peer to allow fail-over in case a peer is inaccessible.

If not using service discovery, your connection profile needs to contain all the network nodes that your client application might need to connect to in order to transact. This must include enough endorsing peers (from enough organizations) to allow transaction endorsement requirements to be met, and orderer nodes to allow endorsed transactions to be submitted and update the ledger.